# Google Cloud Show File On Page

Tags: asp.net, google-cloud-storage

Nowhere is document about getting files as byte or showing my picture in page.I try all the ways, I have two questions about this topic on stackoverflow but nobody have idea about this.And I must finish my project today.

I use ASP.Net Webform and will show my files on my page can anyone help me ? Getting files as byte is enough for me..

https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/stackexchange is sending me here about cloud storage please help !

Comment: no one can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your objects are public you can display them as images on a page by simply putting them into an img tag.

`<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]"/>`

If they are not public the most efficient way to display the image is probably to generate a signed [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#string-components) and use it in an img tag.

Comment: You save my time I saw the answer next day, but couldn write answer for this great answer . Thank you my friend